# How to you rebase a GitHub fork?

Tags: github

There is a project on GitHub that I have forked. My workflow involves cloning my fork to my local machine.

Occassionally I commit my changes to my local branch. And eventually I push those changes to my fork on GitHub. I do this so I can work on my project at work, push my changes, then go home, pull the latest from my fork and continue working.

At this point, on my branch, I have several commits. I want to link my changes to some people for code reviews, but when I view an individual commit, it's diff is only compared to the previous commit from me. I don't want my peers to have to sift through all my commits trying to understand what changed from the beginning.

Is it possible to specify exactly which commit you are diffing against? In my case, I want to diff my latest commit against the latest commit in the origin branch.

If not, is there a way to rebase a fork on GitHub so that it combines my selected commits into one commit?

Answer (score 0):

In most git based code reviews, it's normal practice to go through and review every commit and comment separately for each one.  This is normally to help enforce good coding practices in terms of commit size and scope and testability.

In the command line, almost all commands support a revision interval as an argument

- `git diff <some commit>..<some other commit>`
- `git log <some commit>..<some other commit>`

and that will give you the results for changes solely within that range

also there is a difference between

`git diff <some commit>..<some other commit>`
and 
`git diff <some commit>...<some other commit>`

as the third dot means inclusive, also showing results for  which defaults to HEAD

In the github web client I don't think you can do this, I just checked their native client and it's a no go as well.

I did just look at Atlassian/bitbucket's [SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) and that allows you to shift-select a range of commits as you're expecting